# Installing Sublime packages from directory path

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a Sublime Text 3 installation in an air gapped machine that contains 50 files with a `.sublime-package` extension.  I'd like to be able to install some of these into my instance of Sublime but I cannot figure out how to get the Package Control system to see the directory.

How do I add a local path to Package Control?

Comment: Is the computer you want to install the packages onto also air gapped or does it have access to the net? Also, were the packages on the air gapped machine installed via Package Control (say with a temporary internet connection of some sort)?

Comment: I'm wondering how to get the .sublime-package files downloaded so I can put them into the directory structure somewhere.